# ESLint no-unused-vars inconsistent across different react projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have two separate react projects that behave in different ways with when they throw a no-unused-vars warning.

The below code is an example of when a warning is thrown by one project but not the other

```
for(const subject of this.props.subjects) {
  subjectOptions.push(<option key={subject}>{subject}</option>);
}
```

**'subject' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars**

From what I understand from the ESLint docs, a warning should be thrown if a variable is only read to and not written to.

Here is another example of when a warning is thrown by the one project but not the other

```
let i = this.props.tags.indexOf(name);
let tags = this.props.tags;
tags.splice(i, 1);
```

**'i' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars`**

The project that doesn't throw the warnings in these two cases will throw the warning for something like the following, when the variable is declared and never read or written to again

```
let a = 5;
```

I used create-react-app to set up both projects

## UPDATE:

I have downloaded uploaded the project that does not throw the errors on github and re-downloaded it. I now have the original version and a copy of the project, and the copy shows many no-unused-vars warnings while the original does not, and I have no idea why, as they are exactly the same

Comment: Are you using create-react-app, a style-guide like airbnb, or are you setting up your own eslint config?

Comment: I am using create-react-app

Comment: "[A] warning should be thrown if a variable is only read to and not written to." On the contrary, no-unused-vars catches variables that are initialized (whether or not written to) but never used (read). Neither of the code samples you posed should cause a no-unused-vars warning since in both case the variable is used. Are you sure these are the lines where the errors are originating? One thing to look for is shadowing: In the first code sample, there might be a `subject` defined in an outer scope and which is unused.